# Restrict Characters Allowed In TextBox(Entering Money Amount)

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, currency, restrict

So I have a Subtotal TextBox where an amount like $546.75 can be entered. Now, I want to make sure that only numbers, ONE decimal, One Dollar Symbol and commas allowed only every 3 places (100,000,000). Is this possible? Maybe not the commas, but at least the numbers, decimal, and dollar symbol.

Comment: Please don't add things like " - WinForm C#" to your titles. That's what we use tags for here.

Comment: ok, sorry, will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using WinForms and not WPF. If that is the case then you could use System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider (you can drag-drop one from toolbox to your form) along with regular expressions to do the validation.

WARNING: The regex pattern string below may not do exactly you want but hopefully conveys the idea.

Some match examples... "$4,000.00", "-$4000.00", "-$400.00"

```
    private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string error = null;
        string pattern = @"^\$?\-?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\-?\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\(\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))\)$";

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, pattern))
        {
            error = "Please enter a US currency value.";
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        errorProvider1.SetError((Control)sender, error);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using winforms, dunno where you got WPF from, thanks a bunch, I'll try this out

Comment: Just tried it and it works perfectly and I love how it shows the error icon! Thanks again!

Comment: I saw the winforms tag so I assumed as much but just making sure since your original question does not explicitly state winforms. Glad to hear it works for you!

Comment: I love it how the OP has a comment "Please don't add things like " - WinForm C#" to your titles. That's what we use tags for here" promptly followed by this answer "your original question does not explicitly state winforms"

Comment: If only there was a way to state things in your question without adding them to your title.

Comment: @blins  I implemented this but I am unable to close the form window unless I clear the invalid text first.  Is there a way to make an exception so that the Close button I have does not depend on the validation of the textbox?

Answer (score 4):

Why you dont put the money sign "$" out side of the textBox (create a label just infrontof textBox), then you will not have to worry about this character, but only about numbers. And it looks better (in my opinion).
Then you can use this code:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar != (Char)Keys.Back) //allow backspace (to delete)
        {
            e.Handled = !char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You still need to allow for thousands and decimal separators, both of which are culture sensitive.

Comment: are you serious? The label idea is great but why do you want to keep the change? lol

Answer (score 2):

All validation should be performed manually on KeyPress event.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers) described validation for numeric values values. You will need to check the '$' sign and decimals additionally.

Comment: Though the currency symbol will have to be taken from the current UI culture rather than assumed to be "$"

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of articles on numeric textboxes

[Numeric TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508533/numeric-textbox)

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/95153

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/NumericTextBox.aspx

I use this one in my projects

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/ValidatingTextBoxControls.aspx

Answer (score 1):

//tb - is the name of text box

```
    private void tb_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        char[] inputChar = e.Text.ToCharArray();

        if (char.IsNumber(inputChar[0]))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

// another method.

```
        if (char.IsDigit(inputChar[0]))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Ajax Controls?

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-AJAX-FilteredTextBoxExtender-Control-Example.aspx

Simples. :)