# How to create a box to input numbers that works like Windows Calc input box?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, label, numeric

I read on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/508616/1324082) that Windows Calc do not use a Label not a Text Box to show the inputed numbers. As I'm new on programming I would like to know how can I use a Label to work like Windows Calc's Label on the calc I'm developing.

Comment: Which comment are you referring to?

Comment: @Joe sorry I forgot to hyperlink it, now you can access the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `Label` control on the form and then put buttons for the numbers and, the operators. When a number is pressed, simply update the `Label`'s `Text` property by appending the number at the end. (The initial value of the label should be `0`.) When an operator is pressed, perform the operation on the value (take the label's `Text` property and convert it to a number using the `Convert` class). If the operation needs two numbers, you may have to store the first number and clear the label for a new number entry. Once you have two input numbers, just perform the operation on them and show the result.

If you also want to **display the operation** (similar to how Calculator does it), put another label on top of the first one and just use its `Text` property to show/clear the operation as needed.

If you want to be able to **press number keys on the keyboard**, add keyboard event handlers ([`KeyPress` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx)) to the form that hosts the label and then update the label as needed when a numeric or operator key is pressed. Make sure to set the [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property to `true` so that your form will receive all keyboard input first - this way you can direct number keys to your label.

Comment: +1. and you should set keyPreview to true to get key_down events if the form didn't have the focus

Comment: @hamed Yes, you're right, thank you for adding the `KeyPreview` detail. I'll update the answer.