# C# Deleting last character in a string / textbox.

Tags: c#, string, character, erase

I want to do something like a calculator erase button or to be more specific 
I want to delete the last character when a textbox is changed and not a number is written.
Like in Java I guess you could use CharAt() method but how about C#?

Comment: Allow me to demonstrate the website Google, as I search for [`remove last character in string c#`](https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+last+character+in+string+c%C2%B7&oq=remove+last+character+in+string+c%C2%B7&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.3035j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=remove+last+character+in+string+c%23) and find not 1, not 2, not even 3, but 4 duplicates of this exact question on StackOverflow alone

Comment: @tnw same question but worth noting that the other accepted answer isn't applicable (other answers are)

Comment: Why do you edit the whole question to replace it with a completely different one? Create a new one (this on closed)

Comment: Do not edit your question to make it *completely* different and then try to get it reopened by saying it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

For the text box, just handle the `KeyPress` event, like this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only real answer so far...the question is poorly titled and worded.  It's really about ensuring _only digits_ get entered.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Even more confusing, OP seems satisfied with Daniel's response anyway.

Comment: @DonBoitnott How do you know that this is the real answer? Maybe he already got that and did not know how to delete a char. The question was clear to me: How to delete last Char in String. Anyway +1 for Karl's answer because it will complete this whole mess

Comment: @tnw I agree, it is, but the wording is there nonetheless.  Perhaps Daniel is right, I dunno.  Just seemed like too many people jumped before reading.

Answer (score 2):

Try substring:

```
var myTextBox = GetMyTexBoxFromSomewhere();
myTextBox.Text = myTextBox.Text.Substring(0, myTextBox.Text.Length - 1);
```

In the spirit of doing it "right"... if you're using windows forms:

```
private void tbCalculatorLikeInput_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) 
        && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) 
        && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    // only allow one decimal point
    if (e.KeyChar == '.' 
        && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

And if you're using ASP.NET WebForms:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtNumbersOnly" Runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator  Runat="server" ID="valNumbersOnly" ControlToValidate="txtNumbersOnly" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter a numbers only in text box." ValidationExpression="(^([0-9]*|\d*\d{1}?\d*)$)">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

And if you're using HTML5 / MVC:

```
<input type="number" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume you would rather want to use `NumericTextBox` like shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) by subclassing `TextBox` and overriding OnKeyPress.

There are other examples like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508533/numeric-textbox)

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
stringName = stringName.Remove(stringName.Length - 1);
```

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx

Put the code into the TextBox.TextChanged Event-Method